# How to display a message in console using a seeder class in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

To display an error while using Laravel Artisan the [official Laravel 5.8 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-output) says:

> $this->error('Something went wrong!');

But what's the context of `$this`?

Following is the contents of the seeder class file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PopulateMyTable extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->info("Console should show this message");
    }
}
```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Got it, but how? Do I need to wrap about in Artisan::command?

Answer (score 15):

You can do it by `$this->command->method()`.

Where `$this` is this [Seeder](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.html) instance, 
`command` is this seeder console [Command](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Console/Command.html) instance,
and `method()` could be any of the command available output methods.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $message = 'sample ';
        $this->command->info($message . 'info');
        $this->command->line($message . 'line');
        $this->command->comment($message . 'comment');
        $this->command->question($message . 'question');
        $this->command->error($message . 'error');
        $this->command->warn($message . 'warn');
        $this->command->alert($message . 'alert');
    }
}
```

Comment: How to save this post?